Old house new wires - 30 A dryer on 40 A circuit
I’m getting a new dryer and redoing the utility room. The old dryer was on a 10-30 plug, 40 amp double pole breaker with massive aluminum wire. The 40 amp breaker is on a part of the mains that has no shutoff so I can’t replace it without full house shutoff. I was initially going to splice in 8/3 and extend it but saw the aluminum and changed my mind. Instead, I was thinking of running 8/3 romex all the way from the new plug location to the breaker and a 14-50 plug. That means everything from plug to breaker should be code compliant. Now the question:
I know an 30 A rated device is safe on a circuit rated for 40 A other than the potential for a fire inside the dryer if ALL internal dryer protections fail. Other than that bit, is it okay (aka safe/code compliant… I know those aren’t the same) to use a 14-50 range cord for the dryer in this setup? Barring getting an electrician out to power off the whole house and put in a 30 amp breaker, does this combination sound good?

You should check the instructions for the dryer, it may require a 30-amp breaker anyway.

What type of panel is it that requires an electrician to swap a breaker?  Pushmatic?   On the normal panels, Square D, GE, CH, BR, C, QP, MP, the breakers are designed to be safely exchanged.

Aye, what make and model is your panel? (If you can't identify it, post photos of it, including the label on the inside of the door, and we can figure it out from there)

@Harper-ReinstateMonica That's true. But I 100% understand somebody new to all of this being a bit reluctant to swap breakers without having a main breaker handy - even if it turns out they don't need it, it is good to know it is there in case there turns out to be any kind of problem.

It’s a cutler hammer, not sure of the model, but it definitely appears to be one of those rule of 6 panels where one of the 6 is the main for all of the outlets and lights in the house while the fridge, dryer, AC, and furnace are mains. There is a 60 amp breaker that is unlabeled that I need to track down because with it, the mains breakers add up to 230 A. I’ll try to find the model number.

You would need the utility, not an electrician, to remove power in order replace the breaker in a dark box.  An electrician wouldn't ask for that, they would just replace the breaker in the live panel.  You'll pay their minimum callout rate if you do all the rest (or already have!).  If that's the only part you're not comfortable with, find an electrician to do that.

I think you are right to not do the swap yourself given the age of the panel and the lack of a main switch.   The thing I'd be most afraid of is removing the old breaker, for the first time ever trying that task, without damaging it.  If you break the casing you're really stuck.  If you had a main switch, could learn the feel of this panel and these breakers with the power off, or if you had more experience, doing the swap on a live panel would THEN be easy.

The breaker protects the wire based on very specific rules and it protects the device based on the device's specification.
The standard for a residential resistance electric clothes dryer is:

30A breaker
10 AWG or larger wire
14-30 receptacle (in the past 10-30 was allowed and still allowed grandfathered (does not apply here) but very much not recommended)
Dryer typically rated at 24A (which just fits 30A with a derate for continuous use) and typically specifies a 30A breaker

What you have here is:

40A breaker
8 AWG cable - which is rated for 40A
14-50 receptacle - which is allowed for both 40A and 50A circuits
But almost certainly: Dryer rated at 24A that specifies a 30A breaker

So you are great on the wire and receptacle. Not so good on the dryer. Which means if there is an overload in the 30A+ to 40A range, or actually a bit more than that (see "trip curve"), the wire will be protected as specified in code but the dryer might have problems. Is it likely that the dryer will have problems? No. A dryer, like most appliances, will generally fail either by losing power (e.g., a resistance element burns out) or by going dramatically over power (a.k.a., "dead short").
Which means you are about as safe as you can get at the moment but are violating the rules of use of the dryer. Will it actually make the dryer run any differently? No, as it will just use whatever power it needs, just like plugging a 15A appliance into a 20A receptacle (which is perfectly normal) will work just fine.
I suspect you have a Rule of Six panel with the 40A breaker as one of the 6. Assuming that's the case, you need either an electrician who is comfortable with replacing the breaker while live (that should be easy but I wouldn't do it myself, and especially considering that the panel is old and may have other issues) or you need to pull the meter (easy to do but you can't do that without authorization from the utility or else you will get in trouble for breaking the seal).
But what you should do in the end is:

Replace the 40A breaker with a 30A breaker
Replace the 14-50 receptacle with a 14-30 receptacle
Replace the 14-50 cord/plug with a 14-30 cord/plug

There is no reason to replace the 8/3 cable - there is nothing wrong with oversize wires and breakers can normally handle a size or two (sometimes more) larger than standard without a problem.

Thanks! I completely agree about the 30 A being better and want it to be. I’m comfortable with a lot of electricity, but hot swapping a breaker on a panel that is probably 40+ years old in a house I’m learning just is a bit past my comfort point. My dad said let it rip, but he’s a bit of a cowboy with stuff.
Side note… I used a 4” x 2-1/8” metal box with a 1/2” receptacle riser and it sure feels cramped in that box with a single 8/3 going in. Is it just because it’s so stiff? I saw the sizing chart and this box should support way more than just one 8/3 but the bend for an outlet is tight.

What are the consequences of "violating the rules of the dryer"? Loss of insurance if this rarely seen weird defect happens that draws more than 30A plus trip overhead but less than 40A plus trip overhead AND burns down the house?

It probably isn't code compliant to use a cord with a 14-50p or 40A breaker. Where you start is at the beginning of the Code, NEC 110.3(B):

(B) Installation and Use Equipment that is listed, labeled, or both, or identified for a use shall be installed and used in
accordance with any instructions included in the listing, labeling, or
identification.

This section defers to the product listing organizations (UL,CSA, ETL) that identify safe operation conditions of "listed" equipment.
So if your instructions say (example from GE) to use a:

Dryer power cord kit (not provided with dryer) UL rated 120/240V, 30A

and

This dryer should be connected to an individual branch circuit with 10
gauge copper wire minimum through a 30 amp fuse or circuit breaker. DO
NOT fuse neutral. Use copper conductors only.

You really don't have many options. Using a 14-50 cord may seem like a good idea, but I suspect that the specific requirement for 30A cord is to prevent it from being plugged into an existing 40 or 50A circuit.
